# how to iterate through json data from api in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I just started learning React and am trying to loop through an array of JSON data. However, I am getting some syntax errors. I'm trying to use the `array.map` function, but it's not working properly, and I'm not exactly sure how to implement it to make it display each element in the JSON array instead of just one. Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';

import UserForm from "./components/UserForm.js";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    stars: "",
    icon: "",
    trails: [], isLoaded: false
  }
  getUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const address = e.target.elements.address.value;
    if (address) {
      axios.get(`https://www.hikingproject.com/data/get-trails?lat=40.0274&lon=-105.2519&maxDistance=10&key=200279581-dd891420fa2c470dbb683b34e017062a`)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          const trailList = res.data.trails.map((trail) => {
            console.log(trail.name)
            console.log(trail.stars)
            return <div> <p>{trail.name}</p> </div>
          })

          this.setState({ trails: trailList, isLoaded: true });

          const name = res.data.trails.name;
          const stars = res.data.trails.stars;
          const icon = res.data.trails.imgMedium;
          this.setState({ name });
          this.setState({ stars });
          this.setState({ icon });
        })
    }

    else return;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <h1 className="App-title">HTTP Calls in React</h1>
          </header>

          <UserForm getUser={this.getUser} />
        <div className="newmessage">
       {this.state.trails.map((obj) => {

         return( 
            <div>
            <p>{obj.name}</p> >
                    <p> {obj.stars}</p>
                       </div>
                    );
            }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please specify exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: syntax error ...

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to fetch your data in the `componentDidMount` either with `fetch` or `axios`. Never used axios, so I am going to answer the question with `fetch`

Leave the constructor as it is. Then write a `componentDidMount` like so:

`componentDidMount() {
     fetch('https://www.hikingproject.com/data/get-trails?lat=40.0274&lon=-105.2519&maxDistance=10&key=200279581-dd891420fa2c470dbb683b34e017062a')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ trails: data.trails }))
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
}`
 
then in a sub-render method, such as `renderData`, write the following code:

```
renderData() {
    if (!this.state.trails) {
        return null;
    } 
    return this.state.trails.map(trail => <p>{trail.name}</p>);
}
```

Then call `{this.renderData()}` in your `render`

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.renderData()}</div>
    )
}
```

This code has been tested on my local environment and it was working as it should.